cannot execute binary file error with vmware-ovftool 4.6.3
We used to execute the below command from our shell successfully using vmware-ovftool version 4.3.0
[root@localhost ~]# /bin/sh VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-7948156-lin.x86_64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
[######################################################################] 100%
The system is up to date. Nothing has been modified.
[root@localhost ~]

But in the latest vmwware-ovftool 4.6.3, only the zip file seems to be available instead of the bundle file, due to which the following command is failing in the same environment.
[root@localhost ~]# /bin/sh VMware-ovftool-4.6.3-24031167-lin.x86_64.zi
VMware-ovftool-4.6.3-24031167-lin.x86_64.zi: VMware-ovftool-4.6.3-24031167-lin.x86_64.zi: cannot execute binary file
[root@localhost ~]#

Could you please let us know if there is any simple procedure to overcome the above failure?
